# How to calculate bulletproof scrolling progress

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, progress, user-experience

I am calculating scrolling progress (% of document hidden from view after scrolling down) on a page with the following line:

```
window.pageYOffset / document.body.scrollHeight
```

This works well for most sites. But some sites tweak the scrolling or the overflow property and in effect break the above calculation.

For example, [on this page](https://medium.com/best-of-tech/dc1677f185e7) the above line will always return `0`.

Is there a better way to calculate scrolling progress that would work in situations like these?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach :

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    let limit = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, 
    document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    document.documentElement.offsetHeight );

let footerHeight = document.querySelector('footer').offsetHeight; 

let max = limit - window.innerHeight - footerHeight;

let height =  window.pageYOffset / max * 100;

height = Math.min(100, Math.max(0, height));

const loader = document.getElementById("loader-scroll");

loader.style.width = 0 + height + "%";
}
```

It works fine across most browsers